# How can I scoop up my plundered space-booty?

Tags: frontier-elite-2

I've decided that the space pirate life is for me. I have a decent ship (Asp Explorer) and have equipped all the necessary stuff I need to chase targets through space (radar mapper and hyperspace cloud analyzer) plus some decent weaponary.

I can blast my targets out of space easily, their loot then goes flying but I just can't pick it up. I have a fuel scoop (converted to a cargo scoop) but can't figure out how to activate it. The cargo goes flying off into space so I chase after it - but it's moving at one speed, I'm moving at another in different directions and by the time I catch up with it I just crash into it and destroy myself. There's no prompt to 'trigger cargo scoop' as far as I can tell, I just approach it and then explode.

What am I doing wrong?

Am I missing a vital piece of equipment needed to scoop this stuff up? Can only certain type of products be scooped? Is it just my bad maneuvering that's to blame?

Frontier:First Encounters makes reference to a tractor beam, but I only have Elite 2: Frontier and don't think this attachment is available. If it were that'd be ideal, but no space ports seem to stock it so I guess it's not available in this game.

Comment: Make sure you have free cargo space, and approach the loot *slowly*. You can't just slam into it at 1000 km/s and expect that the cargo scoop can handle it :)

Comment: @Luaan: OK, so does it matter which position the loot is compared to my craft (loot underneath ship, loot to the nose)? Or is just being near enough to it relative to my ship itself appropriate?

Comment: I've always been looting from under the ship (this helps you not to smash right into it), but I believe you have to have it in a "down-and-forward" segment. It might also be that different ships have the scoop mounted differently, but just make sure you don't smash into it and you'll find out soon enough :)

Comment: it is trickier to scoop up cargo in Frontier than it was in Elite.  In the former I find that cargo often smashing in to your hull instead.